# how to pass environment variables into dtach?

Tags: environment-variables, dtach

any ideas how to get environment variables into `dtach`?  they don't seem to be inherited by default...

```
FOO=bar && dtach -c /tmp/a-socket env
# env does not include $FOO
```

[edit]

because of Reasons (TM) I need to have some sort of command separator in there.  Either a ; or a &&.

(I appreciate now that this is not a dtach-specific question, it just reflects my poor understanding of shell...)

Comment: what's the `&&` for?

Comment: I needed it because reasons.  I now see that's what was causing my problem...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `export` is not needed as well. `export` means that:

> Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of
>   subsequently executed commands.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE
>   before exporting.

You can expose environment variable with the following command schema:

```
FOO=bar dtach -c /tmp/a-socket env
```

It will not cause a *side effect* that next child-process (so executed command) will inherit `FOO=bar` environment variable.

Commenting your first execution try. It does not make sense to add `&&` operator between configuring environment variable and running the process. It runs nothing (exit code == `0`) and then runs your command without environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `&&` is functioning as a command separator (specifically only execute the second command if the first succeeds). This is probably not what you want consider the following examples:

```
name=value;$command
name=value||$command
name=value&&$command
```

in all three of these cases name is set to value in the current shell and in the first and third cases the command  $command  is then executed because assignment will never fail and in the second case $command is not executed because assignment will never fail (possible exceptions in odd shells with reserved variables). In no case is the variable passed to $command.

```
name=value;export name;$command
export name=value;$command
```

Omitting similar examples with the other command separators, these examples add an export which passed the variable to $command and every other command executed hereafter in the current session.

```
name=value $command
```

Note the absence of a command separator. In this case the variable is passed to $command and only command, it is not used in the current shell.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, with apologies:  if you really must have an `&&` or `;` command separator, then you have no choice but to use `export`:

```
export FOO=bar; dtach -c /tmp/a-socket env
# this time env will show FOO=bar
```

you could add an `; unset FOO` at the end if you don't want to pollute your main shell...